# Como fazer um split por números dentro da string?

Tags: c#, string

Segue string:

```
1No começo Deus criou os céus e a terra. 2A terra era um vazio, sem nenhum ser vivente, e estava coberta por um mar profundo. A escuridão cobria o mar, e o Espírito de Deus se movia por cima da água.
3Então Deus disse:
— Que haja luz!
E a luz começou a existir. 4Deus viu que a luz era boa e a separou da escuridão. 5Deus pôs na luz o nome de “dia” e na escuridão pôs o nome de “noite”. A noite passou, e veio a manhã. Esse foi o primeiro dia.
6Então Deus disse:
— Que haja no meio da água uma divisão para separá-la em duas partes!
7E assim aconteceu. Deus fez uma divisão que separou a água em duas partes: uma parte ficou do lado de baixo da divisão, e a outra parte ficou do lado de cima. 8Nessa divisão Deus pôs o nome de “céu”. A noite passou, e veio a manhã. Esse foi o segundo dia.
9Aí Deus disse:
— Que a água que está debaixo do céu se ajunte num só lugar a fim de que apareça a terra seca!
E assim aconteceu.
```

Ou se preferir JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtzf525j/1/

Quero que retorne algo assim:

```
1 No começo Deus criou os céus e a terra.
2 A terra era um vazio, sem nenhum ser vivente, e estava coberta por um mar profundo. A escuridão cobria o mar, e o Espírito de Deus se movia por cima da água.
3 Então Deus disse: — Que haja luz! E a luz começou a existir.
```

Como posso separar cada versículo ?

Comment: "*string é int*" seria valores inteiros no texto? E existe a possibilidade de haver números inteiros dentro do versículo que não seja a indicação do mesmo: "*Pedro comeu 3 laranjas*"?

Comment: Dentro de uma string separar quando for número. Agora "Pedro comeu 3 laranjas" me pegou .

Comment: Isso daí sai por [regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Então, pensando aqui, sempre vai serum espaço depois do primeiro caracter?

Comment: Isso mesmo @LuizSantos

Comment: e s string vai ser sempre uma lista assim?

Comment: @LuizSantos isso mesmo.

Comment: Não sei porque "alguém" deu negativo na minha pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que vi, cada versículo é imediatamente seguido de letra, sem outro separador, certo?

Você resolve seu problema em quatro passos:

- Crie uma expressão regular para encontrar o número de cada versículo:

```
Regex r = new Regex("([0-9]+)[a-zA-Z]{0}"); // Pega o número completo "colado" a um texto
```

- Substitua todos os números de versículo por um separador que normalmente não aparece na Bíblia:

```
string testamento = r.Replace(capitulo, "@");
```

- Quebre o texto como faria normalmente:

```
string[] versiculos = testamento.Split('@');
```

- Se você só queria o Array com os versículos, pode parar por aqui - ou inserir `(índice + 1)` no começo de cada elemento do Array. Mas se quiser juntar tudo de novo em um único texto, pode fazer o seguinte:

```
testamento = ""; // já declarei o testamento lá em cima
for (int i = 0; i < versiculos.Length; i++)
{
    int numero = i + 1;
    testamento += numero.ToString() + " " + versiculos[i] + quebraDeLinha;
}
```

Epa, e essa variável `quebraDeLinha` aí, daonde vem? Você a declara antes do laço, com as seguintes considerações:

- Se for para uma página você declara assim:

```
string quebraDeLinha = "<br>"; // ou outra forma web de quebrar linha que lhe aprouver
```

- Se for para uma aplicação desktop ou mobile, talvez isso seja mais interessante:

```
string quebraDeLinha = "\r\n";
```

Só mais uma coisa: a Bíblia pode ser muito grande - talvez mesmo cada testamento sozinho seja grande demais para uma única string. Se a aplicação travar ou ficar muito lenta, sugiro estudar o uso da classe [`StringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). Ela foi criada para lidar com a criação e manipulação de textos muito grandes.

Comment: Renan funcionou aqui, obrigado !!!, Só um detalhe: troca `replace` por `Replace` e  `split` por `Split`.

Comment: @MatheusMiranda valeu pelo toque. É que eu sou dependente químico de Javascript, aí as vezes esqueço que o padrão .NET é com os métodos começando por maísculas XD